# Creating custom firewall in Symfony 2.3

Tags: symfony-2.3, wsse

Creating custom firewall using [WSSE](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html)  is fine. But now I want to create custom firewall which doesn't contain methods like `authenticate(TokenInterface $token)` but contain custom methods which contain logic to authenticate and authorize.If we use `WSSE` implementation of `authenticate(TokenInterface $token)` method is necessary as class implements `AuthenticationProviderInterface` interface.Any suggestions?